# how can I change the header name in post hoc test result table?

Tags: python, posthoc, dunn.test

I want to clarify the name of each row and column with specific name. however, it's shown only with the number (1,2,3,4,5...).
I performed post hoc test named as dunn's test, after kruskal wallis test for non-parametric graph. [image]

```
sp.posthoc_dunn(data, p_adjust='holm-sidak')
```

in addition, is there any way to convert the index into int in the table?